# how to get callback response in promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm using promise inside a promise and calling external functions to get data. The external functions using a callback to send the data back. Could someone please help how to send callback response to promise? below is my code

```
function processData( data ){
....
}

function getData( data ) {

   const callbacks = {
     error(e) {
      console.log('error',e)
     }
     dataReady(data){
      // I want this data to be sent back to my original promise, while which use in processData function
      return data
    }
  }
  const obj = api.init( args, callbacks);

 // TODO: 1) How can I wait this function to complete the callbacks
           2) How can I capture callbacks response 

}


new Promise( ( res, rej ) => {
const req = new Request( args );
req.send()
  .then( getData )
  .then( processData )
  .then( ( data ) => res( data ) )
  .catch( ( err ) => rej( err ) );
} );
```

Comment: create and return a Promise ... resolve the value

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide some example please? may be using my code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mCH5abwt - though, the rest of your code looks odd with that Promise that never resolves

Comment: I've updated my promise to resolve the response

Comment: @Nagesh It is `getData` that should return a promise, not the place where `getData` is used.